# Transfer an old version of an App from iPhone to iPhone

Tags: iphone, applications

I am using an old version of an App (update is available on App Store but I haven't updated it) and I want to install it on a second iPhone (same version, not the new one).

I am running the latest version of iOS 10. Is there a way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you connect your iPhone to your computer and install apps and all of your synching and such through iTunes, all of your iPhone apps will be stored in your iTunes media/ mobile applications folder. From there, all you need to do is find the app and copy it to the location of your new iPhone’s same media folder and you should see it available to install when you have your new iPhone connected through iTunes.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: There are no apps shown on the folder and in the apps list in iTunes. Do you have any idea why?

http://imgur.com/KEicgtz
http://imgur.com/eCMHgo6

Comment: I'm not in front of my computer right now so I cannot take any snapshots for you… I believe for applications to show up in that folder you need to choose to sync your iPhone to the computer and not iCloud, in iTunes

Comment: When I select transfer purchases from device in iTunes nothing happens. This is very strange!

Comment: @Andrei I added another screenshot to my original answer. You need to back up your iPhone to your computer for the files to show up in Finder.app